# Trigger: How does the inserted table work? How to access its rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have the following table

```
Data --Table name
ID -- Identity column
PCode -- Postal Code
```

I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig
ON Data
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 

    Select * from inserted

END
```

And inserted the following values

```
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (125)
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (126)
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (127)
```

It shows this:

[image]

But I was expecting something like this:

- After the 1st insertion, the trigger is executed -> one row is shown in the `inserted` table.
- After the 2nd insertion, the trigger is executed -> two rows are shown in the `inserted` table.
- After the 3rd insertion, the trigger is executed -> three rows are shown in the `inserted` table.

According to [msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) all the rows inserted are in this table.

---

How can I access the `inserted` table so that I can see all the expected rows and not separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not. From the [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) article on microsoft.com, you can read:

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT and UPDATE statements.

That means that the `inserted` table will only contain rows for the current `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

If you do want to see all rows for several such `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, you will have to store these rows in a table you created yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 table available in a trigger, the inserted and the deleted.  Each update on table XXX is actually a delete row X from XXX then an insert of row X in table XXX.  So the inserted inside the trigger is a copy of what got inserted. You can do a lot with a trigger, but triggers are dangerous.

For example, on a performance gig, I found a huge SP being run by a trigger, we dropped it and the database came back online. Or another example, if you do a trigger wrong to audit logins, you can down the server.

Answer (score 0):

As TT mentioned, if you want to see all the inserted records then you need to change your Trigger to something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig
ON Data
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 

    Select * into "tablename"
    from
    (Select * from inserted) Ins

END
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you are replying to a question, try to introduce a new point of view against whatever comment or previous reply. If you are not introducing a new POV just adding extra information, please make a comment.