# See time records were inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with no time stamp in any of the columns.

With what I have now in the table and without inserting any rows or redoing everything, is there a way to see what time and / or date a record was inserted?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: okay :(          insert 8 more characters so I can send my sad emoji

Comment: There are ways to parse the log to extract such information -- if the log is available from when the data was inserted.

Comment: Can you join your table data to any other data that does have a date, and was likely to be created around the same time? I had this recently with a db that didn't record the time a deposit identifier was created but did record when the deposit was made. In most cases these two events would be within minutes of each other so I was able to guess

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a trigger in this table which when you insert, it will insert another record in another (or update another to count the times that it is inserted) table with the date and all the information that you want.

Creating a trigger which controls the inserted records is explained in another question in stackoverflow, I leave you the link here:

[Trigger: How does the inserted table work? How to access its rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576424/trigger-how-does-the-inserted-table-work-how-to-access-its-rows)